# Cobol Programming Display Issue, Decimal Place in the output part of the program

Tags: cobol

Can someone please help me how to fix this kind of problem? The output part only displayed one decimal place even if I have inserted two decimal places in the input part.

I already tried all the possible thing that I could do but still it doesn't change.

## Issue/Problem

I typed 1.25 to midterm grade and 1.75 to my final grade in the input part but the output part showed only 1.2 to my midterm grade and 1.7 to my final grade

## Data definition

```
    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 STUD-REC.
       05 STUDNO PIC X(12).
       05 STUDNA PIC X(20).
       05 MIDGRD PIC 9V9(2).
       05 FINGRD PIC 9V9(2).
       05 EOF PIC A VALUE 'Y'.
     
    01 REP-OUT.
       05 FILLER PIC X(5).
       05 STUDNUM PIC X(17).
       05 FILLER PIC X(5).
       05 STUDNAME PIC X(20).
       05 FILLER PIC X(5).
       05 MIDTRM GRD PIC 9.9(2).
       05 FILLER PIC X(17).
       05 FINALGRD PIC 9.9(2).
       05 FILLER PIC X(5).
```

## procedure code

```
    INPUT-RTN.
     DISPLAY SCR.
     DISPLAY 'INPUT: ' AT LINE 1.
     DISPLAY 'STUDENT NUMBER: ' AT LINE 2.
     ACCEPT STUDNO AT LINE 2 COLUMN 18.
     DISPLAY 'STUDENT NAME: ' AT LINE 3.
     ACCEPT STUDNA AT LINE 3 COLUMN 18.
     DISPLAY 'MIDTERM GRADE: ' AT LINE 4.
     ACCEPT MIDGRD AT LINE 4 COLUMN 18.
     DISPLAY 'FINAL GRADE: ' AT LINE 5.
     ACCEPT FINGRD AT LINE 5 COLUMN 18.
     MOVE STUDNO TO STUDNUM.
     MOVE STUDNA TO STUDNAME.
     MOVE MIDGRD TO MIDTRMGRD.
     MOVE FINGRD TO FINALGRD.
     DISPLAY 'OUTPUT: ' AT LINE 7.
     DISPLAY 'STUDENT NUMBER: ' STUDNUM AT LINE 8.
     DISPLAY 'STUDENT NAME: ' STUDNAME AT LINE 9.
     DISPLAY 'MIDTERM GRADE: ' MIDTRMGRD AT LINE 10.
     DISPLAY 'FINAL GRADE: ' FINALGRD AT LINE 11.
     WRITE STUD-REP FROM REP-OUT.
     DISPLAY 'INPUT AGAIN? [Y\N]: ' AT LINE 13.
     ACCEPT EOF AT LINE 13 COLUMN 20.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mre] as code, not images.  The font in the images is so tiny that I can't read it.  Experienced COBOL developers are old.

Comment: Have you tried to zoom in the image sir? The images are readable on my end, maybe you just have to zoom it in for you to see it more clearly.

Comment: No one can search for the question using its content, if its content is an image (and in that case: the image will also vanish later).
No one can copy anything out of there to reproduce it locally either.
So: please _always_ post code as code and messages as text messages.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check it and tell me what can I do to solve my issue/problem with my program. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the code is that it assumes there is some auto-conversion during `ACCEPT`, which may be true depending on the COBOL implementation and settings, but which isn't guaranteed - especially not outside of `SCREEN SECTION`.
The `ACCEPT` - as used - just provides some way to input "bytes" into some "storage" and your storage is `9V9(2)` which means "3 bytes, assumed to be numeric, having an *implied* decimal point after the first place.

With the input "1.25" in there you *may* (depending on the implementation) place three bytes containing "1.2" into the storage.
The `MOVE` to an edited field `9.99` will do some "conversion" of the data and if the data stored is not valid to its `PICTURE`, then you get to undefined behavior.
You could test that by doing your input as plain numbers and see if your program then works "as expected".

In general it is **always important** to verify input data, and that is missing in your code.
I'd suggest to adjust the code doing something similar to:

```
     ACCEPT PIC-X-5-VAR
   *> verify that there was no bad data entered
   *> if that's not available then either drop that part
   *> or test manually via INSPECT
     IF FUNCTION TEST-NUMVAL (PIC-X-5-VAR) <> 0
   *> verify that there we're in the general bounds (TODO: adjust to your rules)
     OR FUNCTION NUMVAL (PIC-X-5-VAR) <= 1
                                   OR >= 6
        DISPLAY "BAD INPUT".
   *> now place the numeric value in there ...
     MOVE NUMVAL (PIC-X-5-VAR)  TO GRADE-VAR
   *> ... and verify there was no truncation (input of "0.111")
     IF GRADE-VAR NOT = NUMVAL (PIC-X-5-VAR)
        DISPLAY "TRUNCATION ON INPUT".
```

all wrapped in an own `INPUT-GRADE SECTION` - with your code style in an own paragraph - that also does the `ACCEPT` and the goes back to the input after displaying the error.